# How to render comments in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, comments, drupal-theming, drupal-comments

I have a template file **node-contenttype.tpl.php**. There I´m trying to print the comments of that node via

```
print render($content['comments']);
```

but only the comment form is rendered. So im looking into the comment-wrapper.tpl.php and the comment.tpl.php. When im writing something in the **comment-wrapper.tpl.php**, for example a little bit of dummy text, it is printed. But when im doing this in the **comment.tpl.php**, nothing happens.

Inside the **comment-wrapper.tpl.php** is the call

```
print render($content['comments']);
```

but no comment is rendered.

So the problem seems to bee that the **comment.tpl.php** is not called. I have find out that the comment Array in **comment-wrapper.tpl.php** is empty, too.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Do you have the devel module installed? What do you see under the render tab? Is the comments array empty too? What you are doing should work

Comment: Yes i have installed that. And yes the comments array is empty. I dont know why because there are 3 puplished comments of this site.

Comment: And the '3 published comments of this site' are supposed to be attached to the exact node you're viewing?

Comment: yes of course is it attached to that exact node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a language problem. The language was set to "english", i have set to undefined and now the comments are rendered.

But i have no idea why..

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Not the best way forward, but you can also use this in node-contenttype.tpl.php

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
$node_view = node_view($node);
foreach($node_view['comments']['comments'] as $key=>$value)
{
    if(is_numeric($key))
    {
        print_r($value['comment_body']['#object']->comment_body['und'][0]['safe_value']);
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: I have copied that in my node--contenttype.tpl.php but nothing. Only the <pre></pre> is printed.